# Spring Context initialization failed while bootstrapping with Websphere 7.x server

Tags: spring

I am working on a migration task where we are migrating the project from Websphere 6.1 to Websphere 7.0.0.39. Also upgraded JDK version from 1.5 to 1.6.

Actually one of the web project, uses spring and hibernate combination. The version of spring is 2.5.3. The spring context is initialized while bootstrapping i.e. @ server startup.

So i am getting **org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed** error while server startup.

I also did a google search on the below issue and found the jira [SPR-4788](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4788) which says spring2.5 && ibm jdk6 will produce a NPE as below.

**Stack Trace from the server startup log :**

```
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@27822782]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@39ed39ed
[5/9/16 16:29:03:417 IST] 0000000c DefaultListab I org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@39ed39ed: defining beans [applicationContextHolder,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,jndiEPTemplate,sequenceProxy,transferActionItemDao,transferTemplateActionItemDao,achActionItemDao,achTemplateActionItemDao,wireActionItemDao,wireTemplateActionItemDao,posPayActionItemDao,cdBalancesDao,bankIRReportsDao,favoriteDao,stateDao,secureMsgActionItemDao,specialReportItemDao,alertsActionItemDao,shortcutMenuDao,userActionItemDao,achAuthActionItemDao,corporateWireBannerDao,wireBannerDao,corporateTransferBannerDao,transferBannerDao,corporateAchBannerDao,achBannerDao,corporatePosPayBannerDao,posPayBannerDao,issuesBannerDao,stopPayBannerDao,uploadBannerDao,corporateIssuesBannerDao,corporateStopPayBannerDao,corporateUploadBannerDao,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,CDBalancesDao,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
[5/9/16 16:29:03:417 IST] 0000000c ContextLoader E org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:579)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:366)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1721)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:732)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:617)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1146)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1320)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:759)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$3.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2082)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5398)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5486)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2087)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$300(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:944)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:496)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(GenericTypeResolver.java:144)
    at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveReturnType(GenericTypeResolver.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.getPropertyType(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:58)
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.setWriteMethod(PropertyDescriptor.java:111)
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.<init>(PropertyDescriptor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.<init>(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:252)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:470)
    ... 39 more

[5/9/16 16:29:03:433 IST] 0000000c webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:579)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:366)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1721)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:732)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:617)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1146)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1320)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:759)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$3.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2082)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5398)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5486)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2087)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$300(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:944)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:496)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(GenericTypeResolver.java:144)
    at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveReturnType(GenericTypeResolver.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.getPropertyType(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:58)
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.setWriteMethod(PropertyDescriptor.java:111)
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.<init>(PropertyDescriptor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.<init>(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:252)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:470)
    ... 39 more
```

**Spring jars in Class-Path of the web project:**

```
3rdparty/spring-2.5.3.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-aop.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-beans.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-binding.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-context-support.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-context.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-core.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-dao.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-faces.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-jdbc.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-js.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-mock.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-security-acl.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-security-core-tiger.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-security-core.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-security-taglibs.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-support.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-test.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-tx.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-web.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-webflow.jar 
 3rdparty/spring-webmvc.jar
```

**Spring Configuration File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/xsd-config.html -->
    <!-- see Spring in Action pg 143 -->

    <bean id="applicationContextHolder" class="com.s1.core.WebApplicationContextHolder" />

    <bean id="dataSource"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.WebSphereDataSourceAdapter">
        <property name="targetDataSource">
            <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
                <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/EPDatabase" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="bankingEjbPersistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="DB2"/>
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="jndiEPTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
      <property name="environment">
      <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">iiop://localhost:@BOOT_STRAP_PORT@</prop>
      </props>
      </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sequenceProxy" class="org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean" scope="prototype">
            <property name="jndiName" value="ejb/com/s1/arch/sequence/SequenceServiceHome"/>
            <property name="businessInterface" value="com.s1.arch.persistence.sequence.SequenceService"/>
            <property name="jndiTemplate">
                  <ref local="jndiEPTemplate"/>
            </property>
            <property name="cacheHome" value="false"/>
            <property name="lookupHomeOnStartup" value="false"/>
            <property name="resourceRef" value="false"/>
            <property name="homeInterface" value="com.s1.arch.persistence.sequence.SequenceServiceHome"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transferActionItemDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.TransferActionItemDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="transferTemplateActionItemDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.TransferTemplateActionItemDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="achActionItemDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.AchActionItemDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="achTemplateActionItemDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.AchTemplateActionItemDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="wireActionItemDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.WireActionItemDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="wireTemplateActionItemDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.WireTemplateActionItemDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="posPayActionItemDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.PosPayActionItemDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="cdBalancesDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.CDBalancesDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="bankIRReportsDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.BankIRReportsDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="favoriteDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.FavoriteDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="stateDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.StateDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="secureMsgActionItemDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.SecureMsgActionItemDao" />
    <bean id="specialReportItemDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.SpecialReportItemDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="alertsActionItemDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.AlertsActionItemDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="shortcutMenuDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.ShortcutMenuDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="userActionItemDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.UserActionItemDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="achAuthActionItemDao" class="com.s1.core.dashboard.dao.AchAuthActionItemDao" autowire="byName" />


    <bean id="corporateWireBannerDao" class="com.s1.pso.core.banner.dao.PSOCorporateWireBannerDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="wireBannerDao" class="com.s1.pso.core.banner.dao.PSOWireBannerDao" autowire="byName" />   
    <bean id="corporateTransferBannerDao" class="com.s1.pso.core.banner.dao.PSOCorporateTransferBannerDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="transferBannerDao" class="com.s1.pso.core.banner.dao.PSOTransferBannerDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="corporateAchBannerDao" class="com.s1.pso.core.banner.dao.PSOCorporateAchBannerDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="achBannerDao" class="com.s1.pso.core.banner.dao.PSOAchBannerDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="corporatePosPayBannerDao" class="com.s1.pso.core.banner.dao.PSOCorporatePosPayBannerDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="posPayBannerDao" class="com.s1.pso.core.banner.dao.PSOPosPayBannerDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="issuesBannerDao" class="com.s1.pso.core.banner.dao.PSOIssuesBannerDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="stopPayBannerDao" class="com.s1.pso.core.banner.dao.PSOStopPayBannerDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="uploadBannerDao" class="com.s1.pso.core.banner.dao.PSOUploadBannerDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="corporateIssuesBannerDao" class="com.s1.pso.core.banner.dao.PSOCorporateIssuesBannerDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="corporateStopPayBannerDao" class="com.s1.pso.core.banner.dao.PSOCorporateStopPayBannerDao" autowire="byName" />
    <bean id="corporateUploadBannerDao" class="com.s1.pso.core.banner.dao.PSOCorporateUploadBannerDao" autowire="byName" />


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
     <context:annotation-config />  </beans>
```

**Persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
   version="1.0">

  <persistence-unit name="bankingEjbPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <!-- The provider only needs to be set if you use several JPA providers 
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
    <provider>org.unitils.orm.jpa.util.provider.hibernate.UnitilsHibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.s1.core.dashboard.bean.AchActionItem</class>
    <class>com.s1.core.dashboard.bean.AlertsActionItem</class>
    <class>com.s1.core.dashboard.bean.BankIRReports</class>
    <class>com.s1.core.dashboard.bean.BankTransactionActionItem</class>
    <class>com.s1.core.dashboard.bean.CDBalancesEntity</class>
    <class>com.s1.core.dashboard.bean.FavoriteItem</class>
    <class>com.s1.core.dashboard.bean.PosPayActionItem</class>
    <class>com.s1.core.dashboard.bean.SecureMsgActionItem</class>
    <class>com.s1.core.dashboard.bean.ShortcutMenuEntity</class>
    <class>com.s1.core.dashboard.bean.SpecialReportItem</class>
    <class>com.s1.core.dashboard.bean.StateItem</class>
    <class>com.s1.core.dashboard.bean.TransferActionItem</class>
    <class>com.s1.core.dashboard.bean.WireActionItem</class>

    <properties>

      <!-- SQL stdout logging -->
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true"/>

      <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction"/>

      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="jdbc/EPDatabase" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />

    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

  <persistence-unit name="parserPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.s1.core.parser.ParsedPDStatement</class>
        <class>com.s1.core.parser.ParsedPDStatementDetail</class>
        <class>com.s1.core.parser.ParsedPDTransaction</class>
        <class>com.s1.core.parser.ParsedPDTransactionMemo</class>
        <class>com.s1.core.parser.ParsedCDStatement</class>
        <class>com.s1.core.parser.ParsedCDStatementDetail</class>
        <class>com.s1.core.parser.ParsedCDTransaction</class>
        <class>com.s1.core.parser.ParsedCDTransactionMemo</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
                      value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect" />
            <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> -->

            <!-- Enable pooling of connections for efficiency. Can be disabled in development  -->           
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" /> 
              <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="jdbc/EPDatabase" />
              <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />

        </properties>
  </persistence-unit>


</persistence>
```

**Listener configuration in web.xml**

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: Upgrade to 2.5.5 as stated in the issue. Also you are using spring 2.5.3 (the fat jar) and also have different module jars (spring-sop etc). Why? That is a possible conflict in versioning, I suggest removing the 2.5.3 fat jar and only use the modules.

Comment: "Upgraded" from 5.x to 6.x?  Both have passed the end of their support life.  I'd recommend getting off of IBM and WebSphere entirely and go to JDK 8.x and Spring Boot.  You don't need that dinosaur.

Comment: Thanks. Upgrading to spring version just worked fine and resolved the issue.